# Create ticket and set attributes via email in Request Tracker 4.2.8

Tags: email, rt

I've managed to configure Request Tracker 4.2.8 to create tickets via email. Can ticket attributes (owner, due date, custom fields, admin cc etc.) be specified in the email? If so, what plugins needs to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two extensions that are most helpful for setting ticket metadata via email. [RT::Extension::CommandByMail](https://metacpan.org/pod/RT::Extension::CommandByMail) allows you to set all of the core ticket data like Owner, Dates, etc. [RT::Extension::ExtractCustomFieldValues](https://metacpan.org/pod/RT::Extension::ExtractCustomFieldValues) is very flexible and allows you to set custom fields by matching text in the incoming email body.

Comment: I have a question regarding RT::Extension::CommandByMail. Is it possible to set tickets attributes via email, but as a comment to an existing ticket?

Comment: I've figured it out. The issue was that the Unprivileged group had no permissions to modify tickets.